# i don't know how to use ' NaN ' in javascript's if command

Tags: javascript, if-statement, nan

Hi guys i know this code is too easy but i'm new in javascript and i'm still learning it . **this code gets a value from user then shows an answer but it dosen't matter if value is number or not it just says = its a number** .

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--Javascript starts-->
    <script>
        var age = prompt("How old are you ?","18");
           if(age == NaN)
           {
               alert("its not a number");
           }else
           {
               alert("its a number");
           }  
    </script>
        <!--End of Javascript-->

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `age` is a string for being the return of `prompt()`. Use `isNaN()` to achieve what you want. [isNaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN).

Comment: btw, nothing is eqal to [`NaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input `age` will be a string. Use `isNaN()` instead. This will work as you expected.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--Javascript starts-->
    <script>
        var age = prompt("How old are you ?","18");
           if(isNaN(age))
           {
               alert("its not a number");
           }else
           {
               alert("its a number");
           }  
    </script>
        <!--End of Javascript-->

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is not entirely correct. For example by entering nothing or whitespaces.

Answer (score 2):

`NaN` is not equal to any value in javascript, not even to itself.

`prompt` returns a string and if you want to check if its a numeric string, check if `age` can be converted into a number using `Number()`.

```
var age = prompt("How old are you ?","18");

if(age != '0' && !Number(age)) {    // extra check for '0'
    alert("its not a number");
} else {
    alert("its a number");    
}
```

couple of  corner cases that should be kept in mind in code above:

1. `'0'` is a `falsey` value, so if `age` is `'0'`, this condition `!Number(age)` will evaluate to true. To prevent this, add an extra check to make sure `age` is not `'0'`
2. empty string `''` when coerced to a number evaluates to `0` and hence the condition `!Number(age)` will correctly evaluate to true whereas `isNan(age)` will evaluate to false which will lead to the execution of `else` block.

Comment: You can supply `isNaN` with strings. `isNaN("18")` returns `false` as expected.

Comment: @Phil that's correct but as it had already been mentioned in a comment and also in one other answer, i provided an alternative.

Comment: Picking at straws now but this will falsely flag `"0"` as _"not a number"_

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Added an extra check for that.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <!--Javascript starts-->
  <script>
    var age = prompt("How old are you ?", "18");
    if (isNaN(age)) {
      alert("its not a number");
    } else {
      alert("its a number");
    }
  </script>
  <!--End of Javascript-->

</body>

</html>
```

Can you use isNaN()?

Answer (score 1):

```
(~~age > 0) ? alert('valid') : alert('invalid')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should Learn about **isNaN** function.

Answer (score 0):

only NaN, nothing is eqal to NaN, include itself.

```
var num = NaN;
console.log(num === num); // false
```